# how to access the file system of my local PC from within the docker container

Tags: linux, docker, filesystems

I want to start the following docker container and have terminal access to it:

```
docker run -it docker:5000/builds/build-lnx64-centos7:latest /bin/bash
```

The problem is that inside the terminal I can not find any of the files in my file system. No `~/Desktop` and similar directories.

Question: **how to access the file system of my local PC from within the docker container?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, containers cannot see the file system of their host.

If you want to achieve this, you will have to explicitly "mount" whatever directories you want to see using the `-v` flag, like this:

```
docker run -v ~/Desktop:/host-desktop -it docker:5000/builds/build-lnx64-centos7:latest /bin/bash
```

If you run that command, you will see the contents of your desktop in the container's file system, at `/host-desktop`.

You really would not want your container's to be able to see the entire host file system. That would be dangerous, especially if the container has write permission. You should always only "mount" the exact files/directories you want the container to access.

For the most part, any project I have worked on that uses docker does "volume mounting" so that the container can write files and the developer can easily access them on the host (e.g. selenium tests taking screenshots) or so the developer can edit source code and the container will see the update and hot-reload (e.g. nodejs development). When doing the latter (hot-reload example), it is usually wise to mount in read-only mode.

See the docs for more details: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only